# What is the best way to select comments with user data and additional with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to make list with comments, including data about user and his car, that are stored in another tables.

Controller contained such query:

```
 Charging::available()
 ->with('some.ports', 'shares')
 ->find($id);
```

And I rewrote it to such:

```
Charging::available()
->with('some.ports', 'shares')
->with('chargingComments.user')
->with('chargingComments.car')
->find($id);
```

Thats how `ChargingComments` model looks like:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Charging::class);
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class);
}

public function car() {
    // here 'id' is the row in the table with users cars
    // 'car_id' is in the table with comments  
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\UserCar::class, 'id', 'car_id');
}
```

It returns me data about each comments` user and his car, but btw I have to somehow limit result to 10 rows. I tried to add

```
'user' => function($query) {
            return $query->take(10);
        }])
```

But it didnt work.

Im sure that should be the better way to write this code, but dont know how

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Charging::with('some.ports', 'shares')->with('chargingComments.user')->with('chargingComments.car')->find($id)->latest()->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: Hello & Welcome to SO! [Have you read how to write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It should be a helpful guide to get your through writing a good, concise, and clear answer.